# Determinant of a 2nd rank tensor help and inverse!

Tags: matrices, tensors

I have the following 3x3 matrix

$$U_{ij} = g_{ij} + \epsilon_{ijk}u_k$$

and I want to find its inverse using the fact that it can be written as the linear combination of its symmetric part and its antisymmetric part i.e.

$$ (U^{-1})^{ij} = Ag^{ij} + Bu^iu^j + C\epsilon_{ijk}u_k. $$ The obvious thing to do is to take
$U_{ij} (U^{-1})^{jk}=\delta_i^k$ but I cannot go further. Have I put the indices right in the last equation? How do I proceed? I can raise and lower stuff using $g$ by the way!

Comment: How do you know $U^{-1}$ has that form? Couldn't the $u$ in the equation for $U^{-1}$ be different that that in the equation for $U$?

Comment: Hi Marion, we like and import many of your physics questions, so it would probably be good for you to look for answers at our place too. For example you have just obtained a new answer [here](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/27416/what-exactly-mean-wrap-brane-brane-riemann-surface-sigma_g%24?show=27418#a27418)... Cheers

Answer (score 1):

$$U_{ij} = g_{ij} + \epsilon_{ijk}u^k\tag{1}$$

$$ (U^{-1})^{jl} = Ag^{jl} + Bu^ju^l + C\epsilon^{jlm}u_m.\tag{2}$$

$$\delta_i^l=U_{ij} (U^{-1})^{jl} = g_{ij}Ag^{jl} + g_{ij}Bu^ju^l+ \epsilon_{ijk}u^kC\epsilon^{jlm}u_m.\tag{3}$$

$$\delta_i^l= g_{ij}Ag^{jl} + B(g_{ik}u^k)(g^{lm}u_m)+ \epsilon_{ijk}u^kC\epsilon^{jlm}u_m.\tag{4}$$

$$\delta_i^l= A g_{i}^l + u^ku_m(B g_{ik}g^{lm}- C\epsilon_{jik}\epsilon^{jlm})\tag{5}$$

Using

$$\epsilon_{jik}\epsilon^{jlm}=\delta_i^l\delta_k^m-\delta_i^m\delta_k^l\tag{6}$$

We obtain:

$$\delta_i^l= A g_{i}^l + u^ku_m(B g_{ik}g^{lm}- C\delta_i^l\delta_k^m+C\delta_i^m\delta_k^l)$$
$$=A g_{i}^l +B u_iu^l- Cu^ku_k\delta_i^l+Cu^lu_i$$
$$=A g_{i}^l +(B+C) u_iu^l- Cu^ku_k\delta_i^l\tag{7}$$

Setting $i=l$ and $\delta_i^i=3, u^2=u^ku_k$, we have:
$$3=A g_{i}^i +(B-2C) u^2\tag{8}$$

Comment: Hi again, thanks a lot! But still, for the second term that you set equal to zero how can we find B and C? We still need them but we only have one equation, right?

Comment: Hmm, I see. Still, you end up with a component of the metric right? If we set $i=l$ then $$Bg_k^m = C \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon^{jim} = C \, 2\delta_k^m$$. Therefore, $$Bg_m^m = 2C?$$

Comment: I think that it is almost there!

Comment: I think that in (5) you can use the fact that $g_{ij}g^{jl}=\delta_{i}^{l}$, right? Then equation in equation (7) $A$ is multiplied by $\delta_{i}^{l}$. Therefore the last equation (8) is just $$3 = 3A + (B-2C)u^2$$, right? Ok, forgive my naiveness, maybe I am just tired, but with that equation how can I simultaneously know B and C? By the way, thanks for you patience.

Comment: yes. you are right $g_{ij}g^{jl}=\delta_{i}^{l}$.  You can pick $A=1,B=2C$, the simplest choice.

Comment: Hi and seriously thanks a lot. I am going to keep being naive though. $3=3A + (B-2C)u^2$ is satisfied from the condition you mention, $A=1$ and $B=2C$ but I cannot find the solution of what B or C is. I need it though in order to know the full inverse! (Ok, sorry for all this nightmare!)

Comment: $A=1，B=2C=1$ should be good enough.

Comment: Hi Mike and thanks for the answer. I am struggling to understand why $B=2C=1$ is good enough.  Indeed as long as B is 2 times C all is good. But I cannot just have this in my answer for the inverse, right? Also, let me ask what happens if in the end instead of $B=2C$ we had found $B=2qC$ for some constant $q$. In this case you need another equation to determine the constants $B$ and $C$. Which equation is this?