# Levi-Civita help

Tags: tensors

$\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the Levi-Civita tensor which is totally anti-symmetric. Let $A^{ijk}$ be a totally symmetric matrix. Is it true that
$$\epsilon_{ijk}A^{ijk}=0?$$
I know this is the case for $\epsilon_{ij}A^{ij}=0$ in two dimensions. Also, do we know something about
$$\epsilon_{ijk}A^{kjl}?$$

Comment: $g_{ik}\epsilon^{kjm}x_m=h_i^j$? or $g_{ik}\epsilon^{kim}x_m=h_i^i$?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you are asking!

Comment: Can you double check the indices in $g_{ik}\epsilon^{kjm}x_m$? Should $j$ be $i$?

Comment: Hi! Not necessarily. In any case I found out that maybe this part (the last one) is not well asked. So you can ignore it. I will change my question anyway! Any comments on the first part?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Because

$$I=\epsilon_{ijk}A^{ijk}=-\epsilon_{jik}A^{ijk}=-\epsilon_{jik}A^{jik}=-I$$.

So $I = 0$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful although it confuses me since we usually define volumes in 3d like this. Would you be kind enough to help me with another question as well? In specific with this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029999/determinant-of-a-2nd-rank-tensor-help-and-inverse.

Comment: In any case THANKS A LOT! (I cannot upvote you yet, but will return to do it when I get 15 points!)